# Cannot compile correct fonts in LyX with sweave

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lyx, r, sweave

Fonts in LyX look different when compiled without (first picture) VS with (second picture) sweave:
[image: Compiled without sweave]

[image: Compiled with sweave]

What is happening and how can I resolve this issue? I'm using Windows 10, R 4.2.1 (with knitr and dependencies installed), LyX 2.3.6.1, fonts family Default, base size 11, no LaTeX font encoding, Computer Modern Roman, Helvetica, default typewriter and automatic math.

Comment: I see only  a few differences in spacing, line breaks and hyphens in lines 3-5 of the paragraph, and it seems that all derived of make the line break before  or  after "any". This sould be an edge case where  each solution is almost equally penalized, so in each compilation can take one or another. Not very frequent, but sometimes happen. This probably have nothing to do with Sweave.

Comment: My advice is use the `microtype` package for a better interword spacing and hyphention, probably this will favor a different  but constant format.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's not just spacing, however - the letters in the second picture are also thinner and harder to read. I consistently get these results when compiling without (first picture) VS with (second picture) Sweave, so I believe the issue does lie with Sweave.

Comment: You should compare the latex output in a simple Lyx file and then , *in the same file*,  add the Rnw(nitr) or Sweave modules and some R chunk, and you will see that this does not change ayithing abount fonts in LaTeX preamble. Maybe what you think to see is due to the looseness of PDF viewer at a low zoom level. This is most evident in tables with vertical lines than even can (apparently) dissapear at some scale, but sufficiently enlarged (zoom at 400% or so) you will notice that the line is still is there with  the correct width.